# How to shuffle/randomize ImageView on Android Studio Using Java?

Tags: java, arrays, xml, android-studio, logic

[image]

This is the app, in xml every image have ID and I instantiate them on Main Java file using ImageView img = findByID(R.id.imgViewOnXml), but I can't randomize their position can someone help me how can I store them in an array, I'm having a trouble

Answer (score 0):

Hello if i undrestand you want to create multiple imgs with random positions so you have to instantiate every imga liké this :

```
ImageView i = ImageView(contexte);
i.x=somex;
i.y=somey
```

Comment: I just want to shuffle the image positions, how do I do that?

Comment: I feel like I need to store each images in arrays but I don't know how

Comment: When you create imageview in XML and you use findviewbyid thats mean w find juste the image that you declarate not you instantiate is that clear for you ? Si if you instantiate using the example above and you Can store it into liste liké this : List<ImageView> list=New ArrayList<>;

Comment: Can you please, use english on explanation, I can't understand your local language

Comment: and don't forger list.add(yourimg);

Comment: Should I change the findByID??

Comment: Can u please clarify what should I use on my java to call the ImageView on xml??

Comment: What I wanted to say is if you want to use a lot of ImageView and store them in an array you should use the java constractor like the example and the method  findViewById will not create a New ImageView just will find what already declarate in your xml